# Can not disable sse in gcc

Tags: c, disassembly

I am trying to disable sse and sse2 instructions. I am cross compiling for x86 in a x64 system. I am also using -static to statically link with libc. Although I use -mno-sse and -mno-sse2, when I disassemble the binary I still see a call to strcpy_sse2, any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is highly possible that your library still contains sse instructions. You will have to build the library for your cross system as well and do that without sse instructions.

Answer (score 6):

For 64 bit Use -mno-sse gcc option